# Failed lemmatization

Tags: python, nlp, lemmatization

I'm trying to lemmatize german texts which are in a dataframe.
I use `german` library to succesfully handle with specific grammatic structure: https://github.com/jfilter/german-preprocessing

My code:

```
from german import preprocess

df = pd.read_csv('Afd.csv', sep=',')

Lemma = open('MessageAFD_lemma.txt', 'w')
for i in df['message']:
    preprocess (i, remove_stop=True)
    Lemma.write(i)
Lemma.close()
```

The process of lemmatization goes successfully, there's no any error in the terminal, but openning the file "MessageAFD_lemma.txt", I get this : [(nothing was lemmatized)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX8Dg.png)

The expected result is like:

Input:

```
preprocess(['Johpannes war einer von vielen guten Schülern.', 'Julia trinkt gern Tee.'], remove_stop=True)
```

Output:
`['johannes gut schüler', 'julia trinken tee']`

What goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`preprocess`](https://github.com/jfilter/german-preprocessing/blob/master/german/preprocessing.py#L30) function returns a copy of the texts, instead of modifying the input. So you need to write *the result of `preprocess`* to the file, not the original `i` messages.

Furthermore, `preprocess` accepts a *list* of texts to process, so you must wrap your message in `[message]`, and extract the single result from the returned list with `result, = ...`

```
from german import preprocess

df = pd.read_csv('Afd.csv', sep=',')

Lemma = open('MessageAFD_lemma.txt', 'w')
for message in df['message']:
    result, = preprocess([message], remove_stop=True)
    Lemma.write(result)
Lemma.close()

# Or, to process all messages in one go:
with open('MessageAFD_lemma.txt', 'w') as f:
    for result in preprocess(df['message'], remove_stop=True):
        f.write(result)
```

Comment: The error: "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list" occurs, but even if i try to look at the "lemmatized" variable, the output looks like: ['d',
 'i',
 'e',
 '',
 '',
 'l',
 't',
 'e',
 'r',
 'n',
 '',
 't',
 'i',
 'v',
 'e',
 '',
 'f',
 'ü',
 'r',
 '',
 'd',
 'e',
 'u',
 't',
 's',
...
 'i',
 'e',
 'g',
 '',
 '']

Comment: (words are spelled in letters)

Comment: I think the spelling-out bug was already present in your original code, you just didn't notice because you didn't use the result. It happens when a Python string is used where a list is expected. Try the new code above, it wraps the message in a list and unwraps the results.